# Arguments to pass to Exists function in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Not able to understand about this error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex4.py", line 6, in <module>
    print "does the file exsts %r" % exists(src_file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\genericpath.py", line 26, in exists
    os.stat(path)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

this is my file contents

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists
script,source,desti=argv
src_file=open(source)
data=src_file.read()
print "does the file exists %r" % exists(src_file)
dest_file=open(desti,'r+')
dest_file.write(data)
print dest_file.read()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `os.path.exists()` function takes a *string*, containing a filename. You passed in an *open file object* (the result of the `open(source)` call).

You could use `source` instead, which contains your filename:

```
print "does the file exists %r" % exists(source)
```

Since you already succeeded in opening the file from the filename, there is little point in testing for the existence of the file however.